# How do I follow a recipe if my oven doesn't go as high as the recipe states?

Tags: baking, bread, oven

I want to bake bread. I found this recipe from [Alex French Guy Cooking on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1r6jV-MaQuc). His recipe says that the oven should be 250 degrees Celsius. My oven only goes to 220 degrees. I bought an oven thermometer to confirm and it taps out at 230 degrees. Do I just bake the bread for longer? If so how much longer?

UPDATE:

Here are the instructions from the comments section of the video. I did link the video in the original question but I see the link isn't very visible. (Just in case there is anything else you want to check)

> Ingredients you need : Flour, Water, Yeast, Salt and a Dutch Oven. Yes a dutch oven. It's the perfect way to bake your bread at home. Also, No need for sugar, modern yeast are powerful enough. No need for oil either.
>
> Instructions :
>   40 grams of fresh yeast, 
>   in 600 ml of tepid mineral water, or 15grams dry yeast. 
>   In the bowl of the mixer drop 18g of salt.
>   Then add 1 kg of bread flour and start slowly mixing.
>   Add the water and the yeast.
>
> As soon as everything is properly incorporated, set the speed to minimum, and knead the dough for 10 minutes.
>
> First proofing : Place the dough in an airtight container and let it proof in a warm and dark place for 1 - 2 hours.
>
> Then, Press down the dough, shape as seen in the video.
>   Second proofing : Place the dough in an airtight container and let it proof in a warm and dark place for 30 minutes to 1 hour.
>
> Meanwhile, Heat dutch oven to 250°C or 480°F.
>
> Out of 2nd proofing, Sprinkle the dough ball with flour.
>   Now using razor's blade, score the surface a few times.
>   Squeeze on oven proof gloves, get the dutch oven out, place the dough ball inside. Back in the oven.
>
> I bake my bread at 250°C for 30 minutes, then at 230°C for another 30 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!  **:-)** Could you give us the volume and mass of the bread as the [current answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/91856/34942) cannot be made more exact without exact measurements. **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: Added some more information

Comment: See new answer... **:-)**

Comment: Someone more "seasoned" would need to confirm my idea, but perhaps if you have a BBQ Grill you could put a pan in there to shield from the direct flames, and achieve the temperature a bit easier... monitoring with a grill thermometer of course. My cheap BBQ Grill gets over 800F if I close the lid and turn the flames all the way up!

Answer (score 4):

How much longer depends on the type of bread, the size and the shape of the loaf. The solution I suggest is to obtain a probe-type thermometer (like a meat thermometer) and use that to determine if your bread has baked for a sufficiet time. Many breads are completely baked at around 195F(90C) though I have seen a couple of recipes that call for 205F(96C)

Comment: Volume and mass are unknowns, so this is a correct answer with the data we have...  **+1**

Comment: @cynetta I added the ingredients. It is being backed in a dutch oven so it is oval I guess. I will be baking it in a 4.7 litre, 29cm cast iron pot.

Comment: @uriDiun OK I watched the video and read the recipe. I stand by my answer, especially now that I see the bread is baked in a Dutch oven. Obtain a probe thermometer and bake the bread to an internal temperature of 195F(90C). Remove bread immediately from the Dutch oven using the parchment sling and place on a wire rack to cool. I've baked Italian bread using the same basic method only the loaf is about half the size as French Guy's in a 3.5 qt (US) Dutch oven

Comment: Cool, thanks very much I will give it a try. How regularly should I check the temperature? I don't want to ruin the bread by taking it in and out of the oven too much.

Comment: @uriDiun I'd bake the full hour that French Guy recommends since you can't go above 230C, thake the temperature, see where you are then guess the next time to check it. You should still be OK even if you get as high as  97C, just don't aim for that much. Inside the Dutch oven, it isn't going to change too rapidly

Comment: If you're going to bake often, after following the good advice given here, using a thermometer, also 'knock' the loaf on the bottom, and get a feel for what it sounds like, and the way it resonates. After a while, you won't need the thermometer any more.

Answer (score 1):

- The total weight of the ingredients is 40+600+18+1000 = 1658g
- The volume is 4.6L
- The baking time is:

  - 30 minutes for baking 1
  - 30 minutes for baking 2
- The baking T° is:

  - 250°C for baking 1
  - 230°C for baking 2

*What is the total baking time for an oven that taps out at 230°C?*

As all measures remain the same except the T° of baking 1, they even each other out and you should bake for:

```
250/230*30 = 32.6
```

during baking time 1 and then you still need to add baking time 2 to that equation which gives us:

> Bake for 63 minutes 40 seconds at 230°C

Answer (score 0):

Like with many things while time @ temperature is a convenient shorthand for when to expect things to be done it is NOT the best indicator of "doneness".

There are a number of ways to see if [**bread is done**](https://www.thekitchn.com/fresh-baked-how-to-tell-when-b-106715). I would start with just "*baking it for longer*" as a starting point. Then I would recommend checking the internal temperature for a reading of 93°C (or 200°F) using an instant read thermometer. You can start with the "toothpick" method (a toothpick insert into the bread comes out dry) for a 'quick reading' and then use the thermometer to test it.

Comment: I doubt that the 'toothpick' method is going to work for mostly near done bread the same as it does for some cakes or some pies/tarts. The dough at that temperature will probably not leave any residue on its surface when the toothpick is withdrawn.

Comment: @Cynetta Yes, that is why I said to 'start with' that. Once the toothpick comes clean, then move on to the thermometer. If the toothpick has any residue then one need not waste the time of waiting for the thermometer to get a good reading or suffer the heat loss from an open oven door.